# Is there sleep function in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, sleep

In Mysql, we can use `DO sleep(5) ;` to make a pause. But it did not work in Hive.

Is there any sleep function in Hive?

Comment: Where you need this function?

Comment: The question is : why would you need a sleep function in a Database interface? According to me, such a function should not even exists in MySQL but there are probably some legacy reasons

Comment: I'm dong some monitoring task about Hive. I want the Hiveql to execute for a long time, so that I need not to launch Hiveql task everytime. And some tasks excute for a very short time, I need some method to make it last for longer time to monitor them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `Thread` via reflection to make hive wait for some extra time after processing each row, for instance the following query will make hive to wait for 10 seconds

```
select reflect("java.lang.Thread", "sleep", bigint(10000));
```

Not the best way but it might work.

Comment: It worked and solved my problem, thank you. I will vote for the answer when I hava enough reputation :)